# Trying to find exact word match within separate table field, accounting for negative words

Tags: google-bigquery

I have tried so many different queries to get this one right, but its become a complete mess. Long story short, I am trying to find an exact word match (isolated word separated by spaces) based on 3 separate keywords and excluding any matches that contain negative keywords.

field_name_1, field_name_2 and field_name_3 are positive words. negative_keywords is a comma separated group of words that are first split and then used to negate any results where ut.title contains a negative keyword.

In essence the query is asking: "Find where ut.title has either field_name_1, field_name_2, or field_name_3 but at the same time does not have a word from the split negative_keywords field."

Any help is great appreciated. Unfortunately regex is seemingly not possible because field_name_x are constants. Thanks in advance!

My current overbloated mess of a query below:

```
SELECT ut.i_id as i_id, up.id AS p_id, up.option_id as option_id
    FROM ds_test.table_1 AS ut 
    CROSS JOIN 
(
SELECT field_name_1, field_name_2, field_name_3, SPLIT(negative_keywords ,",")  as negative_keywords, option_id, id
FROM ds_test.table_2 ) AS up 

    WHERE 
(
(ut.title contains " "+up.field_name_1+" ")  or 
(LEFT(ut.title, LENGTH(up.field_name_1+" ")) contains up.field_name_1+" ")  or
(RIGHT(ut.title, LENGTH(" "+up.field_name_1)) contains " "+up.field_name_1)  or
(ut.title contains " "+up.field_name_2+" ")  or 
(LEFT(ut.title, LENGTH(up.field_name_2+" ")) contains up.field_name_2+" ")  or
(RIGHT(ut.title, LENGTH(" "+up.field_name_2)) contains " "+up.field_name_2)  or
(ut.title contains " "+up.field_name_3+" ")  or 
(LEFT(ut.title, LENGTH(up.field_name_3+" ")) contains up.field_name_3+" ")  or
(RIGHT(ut.title, LENGTH(" "+up.field_name_3)) contains " "+up.field_name_3) or
(ut.title CONTAINS CONCAT(SUBSTR(up.field_name_1, 1 , LENGTH(up.field_name_1))," "))  or  
(ut.title CONTAINS CONCAT(SUBSTR(up.field_name_2, 1 , LENGTH(up.field_name_2))," "))  or  
(ut.title CONTAINS CONCAT(SUBSTR(up.field_name_3, 1 , LENGTH(up.field_name_3))," ")) 
and (NOT ut.title CONTAINS CONCAT(SUBSTR(up.negative_keywords, 1 , LENGTH(up.negative_keywords))," ")) 
)

GROUP EACH BY i_id, p_id, option_id

IGNORE CASE
```

For example:

In table ds_test.table_1: field title contains "The X301-p and x301-b are Top of the charts"

In table ds_test.table_2: field_name_1, field_name_2, field_name_3, negative_keywords are respectively:

```
ROW 1 = |x301-f|x301p|x301-p|x301-a,x301-c|

ROW 2 = |x301-b|x301b|x301-d|x301-h,x301-p|

ROW 3 = |x301  |x30  |      |             |
```

ROW 1 would be true. There is x301-p and none of the negative keywords are also in the title.

ROW 2 would be false. Even though there is x301-b in the title, there is also x301-p as a negative keyword.

ROW 3 would be false. Even though there is x301 and/or x30 in the title, they match because they are substrings of X301-p or X301-b, therefore x301 or x30 are not full individual words within the title.

Comment: It would help if you would put couple of examples to illustrate, i.e. what should be matched and what shouldn't.

Comment: Mosha, I screwed up and made it seem like there was only one table, when in fact there are two. I edited the original code. You will see ds_test.table_1 and ds_test.table_2. table_1 contains the title, table_2 contains the positive/negative words.

Comment: I added examples of true/false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is:

- SPLIT negative keywords into repeated field
- Remove negative words
  using `OMIT RECORD IF SOME(title CONTAINS negative)` construct
- Match full words using CONTAINS with surrounding spaces, or to catch beginning/end of the string use custom pattern with LIKE

Putting it altogether using data from your example:

```
SELECT title, field_1, field_2, field_3 FROM (
SELECT title, field_1, field_2, field_3, SPLIT(table2.negative) negative FROM
(SELECT * FROM 
 (SELECT 'The x301-b tops the x301-p' title),
 (SELECT 'The X301-p and x301-b are Top of the charts' title)) table1
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT * FROM
(SELECT 'x301-f' field_1, 'x301p' field_2, 'x301-p' field_3, 'x301-a,x301-c' negative),
(SELECT 'x301-b' field_1, 'x301b' field_2, 'x301-d' field_3, 'x301-h,x301-p' negative),
(SELECT 'x301'   field_1, 'x30'   field_2, '' field_3, '' negative)) table2
)
WHERE title CONTAINS ' ' + field_1 + ' ' OR title LIKE '% ' + field_1 OR title LIKE field_1 + ' %' OR
      title CONTAINS ' ' + field_2 + ' ' OR title LIKE '% ' + field_2 OR title LIKE field_2 + ' %' OR
      title CONTAINS ' ' + field_3 + ' ' OR title LIKE '% ' + field_3 OR title LIKE field_3 + ' %'
OMIT RECORD IF SOME(title CONTAINS negative)
```

**Update:** Since it looks like evaluation of LIKE is too expensive on real datasets, another alternative is to pad title with spaces on both sides before doing CONTAINS check. The modified query below:

```
SELECT title, field_1, field_2, field_3 FROM (
SELECT title, field_1, field_2, field_3, SPLIT(table2.negative) negative FROM
(SELECT ' ' + title + ' ' AS title FROM 
 (SELECT 'The x301-b tops the x301-p' title),
 (SELECT 'The X301-p and x301-b are Top of the charts' title)) table1
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT * FROM
(SELECT 'x301-f' field_1, 'x301p' field_2, 'x301-p' field_3, 'x301-a,x301-c' negative),
(SELECT 'x301-b' field_1, 'x301b' field_2, 'x301-d' field_3, 'x301-h,x301-p' negative),
(SELECT 'x301'   field_1, 'x30'   field_2, '' field_3, '' negative)) table2
)
WHERE title CONTAINS ' ' + field_1 + ' ' OR
      title CONTAINS ' ' + field_2 + ' ' OR
      title CONTAINS ' ' + field_3 + ' '
OMIT RECORD IF SOME(title CONTAINS negative)
```

Comment: Thanks Mosha. This will work except for the case of beginning/end of the string. For instance, if title is 'The x301-b tops the x301-p' then x301-p will not be true for ROW 1 = |x301-f|x301p|x301-p|x301-a,x301-c|   Since it is at the end of the word. I wish there was a way to use regex with contains so I could put WHERE title CONTAINS ' ' + field_3 + $

Comment: Yes, there is a way - I modified query to use custom LIKE pattern to catch it.

Comment: Thanks Mosha. Another question, should I use the same syntax to apply negative as an exact match? For instance OMIT RECORD IF SOME(title CONTAINS ' ' + negative + ' ') ....

Comment: Yes, you can use exactly same predicate inside SOME to do word match

Comment: Thanks again Mosha. I am running the query now. It has been running for roughly 5 hours, yes hours. Hopefully it doesnt timeout. BigQuery seems to take longer when using the 'LIKE' function. Table 1 is 280k rows, Table 2 is 8k rows.

Comment: Another alternative is to eliminate expensive LIKE calls, and simply pad title with spaces from both sides. I will add this alternative to the answer.

Comment: Mosha, I ran the query several times and it seems to be using the negative words globally. Each negative field is specific and related to the positive terms in the same row. The OMIT RECORD IF SOME seems to be applying the negative term to all rows, and not the specific matches with its respective positive terms.